# How to Fetch Records from table in Sql between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

How To Fetch records from a table ? But only those records which `added_on >= '2014/03/01'` and `added_on <= '2014/03/31'`

and currently my sql table field value is `added_on = 2014/03/29 05:23:43`

Please help me out as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple SQL Query

```
select * from table_name where (added_on between '2014-03-01' and '2014-03-31' );
```

You may also want to specify `hh:mm:ss`

```
select * from table_name where (added_on between '2014-03-01 00:00:00' and '2014-03-31 00:00:00' );
```

Both should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, [added_on]) between '2014/03/01' AND '2014/03/31'
```

Comment: But my added_on field is not Date nor Datetime. Its varchar and while comparing these two dates i only want to compare date not time something like this     DATE_FORMAT(ag_master_enquiry.added_on,'%Y/%m/%d') AS DATE,

Comment: I've edited my answer to work with your varchar fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE DATE(added_on) BETWEEN '2014/03/01' AND '2014/03/31'
```